# How to send a click even to a view (it already works but I think it is not the Ember way)

Tags: ember.js

I want to style a button for file upload. I already have a working, but it feels like I dont do it the Ember way.

My view:

```
App.FileUploadView = Ember.TextField.extend({
   (....)
});
```

template:

```
{{view App.FileUploadView name="big-image" file=big-image id="big-image"}}
<a {{action clickUploadView}} href="#">Upload file</a>
```

controller action:

```
clickUploadView: function(){
   Ember.$('#big-image').click();
},
```

I have fiddled around to use the viewName property like this in my template and call it from the controller: `{{view App.FileUpload ... viewName="big-image"}}` but could not get the click fired.

Any thoughts or is this just correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your anchor tag in the view helper and add the action to the view, then target the view.

```
{{#view App.SomethingView}}
  <a {{action daClick target="view"}} href="#">Upload file</a>
{{/view}}

App.SomethingView = Em.View.extend({
  actions:{
    daClick: function(){
      alert('hello'); 
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eHAsexI/1/edit

Or if you just want it to hit the click event of the view, you can just rip out the action all together and leave the anchor tag in the view and it will hit the click event of the view.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eHAsexI/2/edit